# Unable to create geometric network on NHDFlowline - invalid enabled field type

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, trace, nhd

I need to create a geometric network in order to perform a downstream trace on a NHDFlowline data in my ArcGIS.

I have two flowline layers on one of them I am able to create a geometric network and on the other I am not. I have noticed that the difference between this two layers is in the column called "Enabled".

In the working layer this field is an short int type with "domain enabled", the not working layer has simple text enabled field (see the attachement)

I really don't know what is all about. I have no idea how can I change the field type to be able to create a geometric network.

[image: Enabled field in a not working layer]
[image: Enabled field on a working layer]

Answer (score 1):

The enabled field is a flag field which enables or disables an edge within the network. A disabled edge would be as if there was nothing there. This is all discussed in the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geometric-networks/essential-geometric-networks-vocabulary.htm#GUID-8C98DD95-2DF3-40CE-B438-DB5B7D43E324)...

As you noted the working version is a boolean field with a domain, so a valid network. Your other data I guess has been exported at some point and the person who did that did not understand what they were doing and have thus created a text based field for a field with a name which has a special meaning. You could just delete that field and recreate it and set all the edges to True so they will be traceable?

Answer (score 0):

Now I will remember to always check the Enabled field.

The solution was to create a new field, type short with enabledDomain and coded value 1 which stands for True a value.

Thanks for your help, now everything is working well.